# Shellscript Ubuntu Find out if a user entered a specific character

Tags: string, shell, input, while-loop

I want to do a while loop until the user enters ab "@", this is my code but its not working:

```
echo -n "username(email): "
read username 
checkEmail $username

checkEmail () {

username=$1
echo $username | grep "@"
while [ ! $? -eq 0 ] ; do
        echo -n  "username(email): "; read username
done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must define the function before using it. Additionally, check during each iteration of the while loop - your code checks the result of grep only in the first iteration, and the result of `read` afterwards. Try

```
username=""
checkEmail () {
  while echo "$username" | grep -vq "@" ; do
    echo -n "username(email): "; read username
  done
}

checkEmail
echo "Correct email: $username"
```